# Convert MySQL to MSSQL using Migration Assitant

Tags: database-migration, sql-server-migration-assi

I have been trying to convert a few simple MySQL-VIEWs to MSSQL using the SQL Server Migration Assistant for MYSQL.

[image]

I get this error message whenever I try to create the report:

[image]

I do not know where to start. What does "Unparsed SQL" even mean? The columns are fine apparently. There are no procedures or anything that I can see that cannot be migrated. What am I missing?

Comment: Unparsed means that the migration assisstant could not interpret the view's sql code. Allthese database conversion tools have limoted support beyond standard database structure. When it comes to code, you need to convert manually.

Comment: So I might need additional rights to see the SQL-Code for the view for this to work?

Comment: I don't this is an access rights issue. The mogration tool cannot handle the view.

Comment: Ok, then one of the reasons might be that I use an underlying MySQL 8-installation to connect to a MariaDB 10-instance?

Comment: I do not know what the exact reason is. This should be a question for MS suppoet, not for SO. Your question is about a features of a tool, not about programming or software development.